# Calculate pairwise difference within groups and still keep the grouping factor

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to pick, within each group, 3 values that are closest to one another. How do I fix my code?

This data has 11 rows (the full data is much larger but I just want to make a reproducible example). The number of values in the Total column that share the same JobID range from 2 to 9 values. I am grouping values by their JobID and then calculate the within-group pairwise differences, called pdiff. Assuming that I have all the pairwise differences calculated, I will sort the pdiff column using ascending order and then use head() to pick my top 3 values.
The dat1 lines gave me the list of pairwise differences only. The dat2 lines sent me an error

```
 "Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, col, value = c(46, 99891, 99577, 99746,  : 
  replacement has 55 rows, data has 11"


dput(dat)
    structure(list(JobID = c("11 W 29", "11 W 29", "11 W 50", "11 W 50", 
    "11 W 50", "23 E 27", "23 E 27", "23 E 27", "11 W 50", "11 W 50", 
    "11 W 50"), Total = c(145501, 145547, 45610, 45924, 45755, 56425, 
    56383, 56262, 756185, 750110, 751467)), row.names = c(NA, -11L
    ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


dat%>%
      group_by(JobID)%>%
      summarize(dist(Total))


dat1 <- dat%>%
      group_by(JobID)%>%
      summarize(dist(Total))

dat2<-dat%>%
  group_by(JobID)%>%
  mutate(pdiff=dist(Total))
```

The expected result should be a data frame of 55 rows and 3 columns (JobID, Total and a new column (called "pdiff" for example)).

Comment: dat2 is missing '%' (should be: dat2 <- dat %>%)?

Comment: Thanks, Ben. Typo fixed.

Comment: I cannot reproduce dat1. I get: Error: Column `dist(Total)` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 15. What packages are you using (besides tidyverse)? Is this stats::dist?

Comment: @Ben: I used `stats`. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry I'm confused - if you compute a pairwise difference matrix across all 3 jobID's, you would get 55 rows as you expected - but if you group by jobID first, you will only get 19 I believe, right? also, dat1 should not work and give an error (as i mentioned) - instead you could try something like: dat %>% group_by(JobID) %>% do(data.frame(t(combn(.$Total, 2)))) %>% mutate(pdiff=abs(X2-X1)) %>% arrange(JobID, pdiff) --- please let me know if that's what you want, or if not, please provide more details of what result should look like

Comment: @Ben Thank you very much. It works.(P/S: Sorry for my delayed response. I was not at the task for the past week.)